# Do something at irregular intervals while timer is ticking

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, network-programming, simulation

I am trying to simulate Aloha using single threaded time-driven simulation.  At any time any node can generate a frame. I have five node (A to E) and a timer that ticks every 1 second. I want that at any time e.g. 15 seconds elapsed a node creates a frame and then after some time another node creates a frame an so on (at irregular intervals).

```
E.g. (Output)

Time 
1       Node A created a frame.
2
3       Node B created a frame.
4
5
6
7
8       Node E created a frame.
9
10
```

In the code that I have now, any frame is created every second by a node. Nodes are selected randomly.

```
E.g. (Current output)
1     Node E created a frame. 
2     Node B created a frame.
3     Node E created a frame.
4     Node A created a frame.
5     Node E created a frame.
```

a.) I do not want that a node generates a frame every second but at irregular intervals   during the simulation.

b.) Then I have to create a method that does not allow a node e.g. A to generate another frame until a period of time let's say 10 seconds has passed.  If during those 10 second no other node has created a frame then the frame is successfully transmitted at a counter is incremented. If during those 10 second another node has created a frame then both frames (e.g. frame created by A and the frame that was created by this node are not successful).

```
private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            time++;
            Random r = new Random();
            //int rnd = r.Next(0, 50);


            if (time > 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Simulation Finished.");
                timer.Stop();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(time + " " + Node());
            }  


        }

        //Randomly select a node
        private static string Node(){
            string[] nodeList = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(0, nodeList.Length);
            return Convert.ToString(nodeList[index]);
        }
```

Thank you for your help and code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is what exactly? Create something that matches your needs and adds it to the DOM? If you are going for client side changes (asp.net), then you either need websockets to create the request every so much time, or javascript that can interact with the current created ui...

Comment: No this is just a simulation in c# via a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something but couldn't you reset the interval of the timer in the timer_Elapsed event?

timer.Interval = random.Next(1, 15) * 1000;

using System.Timers;

```
public class Simulation {
    private Timer intervalTimer;
    private Timer actionTimer;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private bool writeState = false;
    private int currentTick = 0;

    public Simulation(){
        intervalTimer = new Timer(SetRandomInterval());
        actionTimer = new Timer(1000);

        intervalTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(IntervalTimerElapsed);
        actionTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ActionTimerElapsed);

        intervalTimer.Start();
        actionTimer.Start();
    }

    protected void IntervalTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (writeState){
            writeState = false;
        } else {
            writeState = true;
        }

        intervalTimer.Interval = SetRandomInterval();
    }

    protected void ActionTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (writeState){
            Console.WriteLine(currentTick.ToString() + " " + Node());
            writeState = false;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(currentTick.ToString());
        }

        currentTick++;
    }  

    private string Node(){
        string[] nodes = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
        int index = random.Next(0, nodes.Length);
        return Convert.ToString(nodes[index]);
    }

    private int SetRandomInterval(){
        return (random.Next(1, 15) * 1000);
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
0 D
1
2 A
3
4
5
6 D
7
8
9 B
10 E
11
12 B
13
14
15 B
16
17
18 C
19
20
21
22 A
23
24
25 B
26 C
27 C
28 E
29 B
30
31
32
33 D
```

Also you could use one single instance of Random() instead, otherwise you could get same values in a row in such a "rapid" event like Elapsed. 
Might even be somewhat expensive with new Random in Elapsed.

Comment: Tks however that result is not what I need. I need time to be continous and frames are generated randomly approximately every ten second... e.g. after 9sec do something, then after 22, then after 35, then after 41 and so on. When I say do something it could be any event.

Comment: See E.g. (Output) in question for desired output. Thanks

Comment: Changed the output to write continously. (The output was made with 1-5 seconds random interval)

Comment: Ok noted. So on average every 5 seconds a node should appear right?

Comment: On average every 15 seconds. You can change interval to whatever you want in "SetRandomInterval".

Comment: Ok your output is just an example since in 33 second we should see only about 3-4 letters right?

Comment: As i wrote, my test was with 5 sec interval.
Have you tested the code? You have to be more specific if it does not meet your requirement. Not to be rude but rather figure out the small details yourself and please mark the question as solved, as it "Does something at irregular intervals while timer is ticking" :)

Comment: No I'll test it as I go home. Do not worry I will mark the question as solved and will accept you answer :)